# Fit progressbar to cell height

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am currently using Mottie's version of tablesorter to display some data. I wanted to add a column of progress bar, however the progress bar seems to be too tall and it affects the scroller widget of the tablesorter. It might be really simple but I couldn't figure out how to resize the progress bar to fit the height of the cell. Is there any clever way of doing it? I am currently just hard coding the size...

[Table without progress bar displays correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/aithusa/Lgkrh97x/4/)

[Table with progress bar which affected the height of the row](http://jsfiddle.net/aithusa/Lgkrh97x/5/)

```
$('.progressbar').height(10);
```

Also, does anyone know whether the column of progress bar will be sortable?
Cheers!

Comment: Please check the demos again.. the scroller widget was updated in the master branch about the same time this question was posted.

Comment: The fixed column is now resized to the height of the scrollable table, however there is still a misalignment issue, I saw that there are issues opened on github regarding alignment, so maybe this is still yet to be fixed? Thanks a lot for helping, really appreciate it.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aithusa/yLkqkzpg/3/

Comment: A note to anyone who's is having problem with resizing the fixed column, do all the manipulation on the table before you call the tablesorter, otherwise the height of the fixed column will remain as the height of the original table before the manipulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the progress bar to know how much of its parent container's space to take up, it needs to know how big the parent container is, so set its height in the CSS.

```
table tbody td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Then set the progress bar's height to 100%.

```
$('.progressbar').height('100%');
```